# How to group numeric ranges using CASE WHEN in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, case-when

I have tried everything I could and have looked at as many examples as possible on this.

```
CASE WHEN Average Position < 11 THEN "Page 1"
      WHEN Average Position > 10 AND Average Position < 21 THEN "Page 2" 
      WHEN Average Position > 20 AND Average Position < 31 THEN "Page 3" 
      WHEN Average Position > 30 AND Average Position < 41 THEN "Page 4" 
      WHEN Average Position > 40 THEN "Page 5+" 
ELSE "Other"
END
```

Seems super simple but nothing I have done could get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Studio parser is very buggy, specially when using `AND`/`OR` operators and complex expressions, so keep trying until you beat it.

Looking to your piece of code, notice you do not really need this `AND` operator to do the job.  So simplify it and it might work:

```
CASE
  WHEN Average Position <= 10 THEN "Page 1"
  WHEN Average Position <= 20 THEN "Page 2" 
  WHEN Average Position <= 30 THEN "Page 3" 
  WHEN Average Position <= 40 THEN "Page 4" 
  ELSE "Page 5+" 
END
```

Notice I prefer to use `<=` for readability, but your mileage may vary.  You can use `<` as well.

Comment: Yeah, actually I noticed that the one I was using actually did work, just not as expected. However, thank you for the simplified version!! The problem with both versions though is that it produces the groupings as a metric instead of a dimension. This leaves me not able to create reports like I would with SQL.

Comment: Hmm, I think this problem with dimension/metrics has nothing to do with this code. Probably, "Average Position" is a metric, so any calc field pointing to it will also be a metric. If this is not the case, try deleting the calc field and add it again, because a field with a simple `CASE` condition should not be enforced to be metric.

Comment: I was hopeful that creating it from scratch would have different behavior but it's the same. When going into all fields it says its type text but it's blue in the metrics group and you can't change or move it.

Comment: I think there's something you're missing. Could you provide access to a public version of a dashboard that reproduces this problem?

Comment: I don't believe i am but here you go: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b0ae7d50-101c-428e-8b21-23ea06707de2 I have a lot of experience with this in SQL and at best this isn't working as expected. Can you share an example that does work? I am getting different behavior with different data sources but neither work.

Comment: See if it is working as expected now. I changed your dashboard and it appear to be working. "Position Group" was already listed as Dimension, but it was incorrectly added as 'Data Range Dimension' instead of 'Dimension'. There was also an error related with "Records" field, but I think this is subject to a new question.

Comment: It's frustrating because now yes it works using that spreadsheet but doing the same exact thing with Google Search Console API as a connection does not work. Same exact case when. When adding it from within the report edit it gives an error: " Metric expressions and aggregations are not allowed in this expression." with a type as "text". I think it has something to do with Google Search console. Nothing I can do results in it being a dimension (and I have several other dimensions that work fine) Can you test with Google search console?

Comment: Note: I just updated the dashboard I shared to include a search console connection so you can see that it doesn't work. Weird but looks like a bug. @diego-queiroz

Comment: As I said, you were missing something. In the first comment I wrote `Probably, "Average Position" is a metric, so any calc field pointing to it will also be a metric`. That's the case. However, despite of being a metric or not, the calc field seems to work as expected. I don't understand what different output you expect.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Unlike in your previous example the Position Group is a metric and as a result I cannot use it as a metric. I was hoping I could view it like it was in your previous example when we were connected to the spreadsheet (I need to view each position group and how many records in each position group essentially). Its very strange they behave differently, no?